# Change size of image button dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, runtime, imagebutton

Actually i was trying to implement zoom in a different as my layout contains only ImageButtons, by trying to resize the ImageButton on Button click.
But the problem i am facing is the button is inflated within TableRow and further TableRow is inflated in TableLayout.

```
LAYOUT1.xml

<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TabScrollView" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TabScrollView"
                android:background="@drawable/blackbackground" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/elementTable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="2dp"
                    android:layout_y="2dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </TableLayout>


                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

LAYOUT2.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/elementRow"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

</TableRow>

LAYOUT3.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/elementImage"
android:layout_width="100px"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@null"
android:onClick="onClick"
android:padding="3dip"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

I tried using this code

```
ImageButton ib =(ImageButton)findviewbyId(R.id.elementImage);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
ib.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Size of button remains the same as size of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) after setting the layout params.